# How can I tell if something was written with react vs. react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project I found on git hub, that when run, it looks like a mobile app. But the code looks like it was built using react but not react native.

Is there any way to confirm?

Currently the file has `app.cs` and `app.js` which is why I think it was built with react. Any other way to confirm though? App is also built and open on a web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source code you would find for

React Native:

- `import * from 'react-native'`
- Classes like `View`, `Image`, etc.

React:

- Classes like `div`, `p`, etc.